# Unity strobe light

Tags: c#, visual-studio, unity-game-engine, light

I need help with lighting in Unity 2D.

I have tried using a Area Light.

I do not know if I need/what code to use. I am using visual studio.

The light is not making the scene any brighter. The scene is always normally bright.

Comment: Are you using baked or dynamic lighting? If baked, have you set the objects to be lit as static, and rebuilt the light maps?

Comment: I am not sure how to tell what type of lighting it is. All I see is Mixed, Baked, and Realtime (under the mode drop down menu). That is set to realtime. As mixed and baked is greyed out. Can you start from the beginning of how to do this? I will just delete my current light if so.

Answer (score 0):

For strobe lights, make sure that the light is set to realtime and the containing game object is NOT set as lightmap-static.
The baked/realtime lighting system is to slow for strobe lights, as it only updates every few frames.

Area lights only work with baked/realtime baked lighting, thus don't work for strobe.
Either use a transparent overlay texture that simulates the lighting effect or use point lights instead.